# Sql Server Order Max Values

Tags: sql-server

```
userID  point
111     20 
111     30 
222     40
222     50
```

I want to order like this

```
222 50  
111 30
```

every userId Max value order by DESC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To order by MAX point values

```
SELECT userID, MAX(point) 
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY userID 
ORDER BY MAX(point) DESC
```

Comment: so How I can join another table this table I mean my first table coloumns userId FirstName LastName .. Second table coloumns userID, point I want to order like   
FIRST LAST    USERID POINT
EMRE OZTURK   222     50  
FATİH OZTURK  111     30

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the nicely edited question, I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
select userID, MAX(point) from tableName
group by userID
```

and optionally, to sort by userID as well:

```
order by userID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MAX` function is only relevant inside the `SELECT` statement, so:

```
SELECT userID, MAX(point) 
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY userID 
ORDER BY point DESC
```